# Simulating the passing of a google sheets range to a function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a function call in a sheet/cell as follows:

```
=myPositions(History!B3:B,History!C3:C,History!D3:D,History!E3:E,History!F3:F)
```

I created the "test" function to simulate the function call so I can debug the code. It does not seem that the "sheet.getrange('B2:B')" is simulating the range as passed in the above function call. How do I grab a range in the test function to simulate the ranges being passed to the "myPositions" call?

```
function myPositions(account, security, actions, quantity, price){
  let portfolio = generateFifo(account, security, actions, quantity, price);
  let returnArray = [];
  portfolio.forEach((value, key) => {
    let shares = 0;
    let totalCost = 0;
    let avgPrice = 0;
    value.map(trade => {
      shares += trade.shares;
      totalCost += trade.shares * trade.price;
    });
    avgPrice = totalCost / shares;
    returnArray.push([account, key, shares, avgPrice]);
});
return returnArray;
}

function test(xx){
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('History');
  let account = sheet.getRange("B2:B");
  let security = sheet.getRange("C2:C");
  let actions = sheet.getRange("D2:D");
  let quantity = sheet.getRange("E2:E");
  let price = sheet.getRange("F2:F");
  let testArray = [];
  testArray = myPositions(account, security, actions, quantity, price);
  return testArray;
}
```

Comment: `.getRange().getValues()`

Comment: consider filtering off nulls that use of such range definitions often generate